# Laravel 4 Controller Templating / Blade - Correct method?

Tags: view, laravel, laravel-4, conventions, laravel-blade

I've been reading through the Laravel 4 documentation and have been making a demo application to help with learning.

I couldn't find much documentation on the templating of views with blade and controllers.
Which is the correct method or does it come down to personal preference?

**E.g. 1**

**Controllers/HomeController.php**

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.main';

public function showWelcome()
{
    $this->layout->title = "Page Title";
    $this->layout->content = View::make('welcome');
}
```

**Views/layouts/main.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

**Views/welcome.blade.php**

```
<p>Welcome.</p>
```

**E.g. 2**

**Controllers/HomeController.php**

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.main';

public function showWelcome()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('welcome');
}
```

**Views/layouts/main.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**Views/welcome.blade.php**

```
@section('title', 'Welcome')
@section('content')
// content
@stop
```

What is the best convention and/or advantages of the the above?

Comment: Please correct me if the above examples or not the correct way as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't store any layout information in the controller, I store it in the view via

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

When I need to return a view in the controller I use:

```
return \View::make('examples.foo')->with('foo', $bar);
```

I prefer this approach as the view determines what layout to use and not the controller - which is subject to re-factoring.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like either of them. Layouts are probably the weirdest part of Laravel. The controller version doesn't really make sense; all methods of the controller then require that view. The @yield version is a mess of boilerplate. I made up this "method specific layouts":

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('layouts.main', [
        'layout_data' => 'sup'
    ])->nest('content', 'welcome', [
        'view_data' => 'sup'
    ]);
}
```

I think it should be mentioned in the docs that this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere the second one, because it shows a more clear separation between your view and controller code. It seems more logical to me that title would be a property of a content view instead of combining your welcome view with your welcome title each time.

In the end both are correct and will work, but the second alternative is more maintainable.

Comment: I agree, that's the one i've continued to use but i thought it might good to put this question out here... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the 1st method since some sites have a dynamically generated title from the database. It's easy to pass the title in using the first method.

Comment: It is true that most of the content would probably come from a database, but I think you should pass the resulting Eloquent models to the view and set the title there instead of scraping of the title in your controller. You would still pass the model for the content or set the content as well (as well as any other property).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean Aloys?

Comment: This is what I propose (could still be betting using IoC, but that is not important for now): http://paste.laravel.com/vre