# Laravel 4 Blade templates documentation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel 4. I don't seem to find adequate documentation on the Blade templating system.

I see some examples at **http://laravel.com/docs/templates** with no explanation.

Another example at **[Laravel 4 Controller Templating / Blade - Correct method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951010/laravel-4-controller-templating-blade-correct-method)**

Where are @section, @yield, @show, etc defined and documented? Where is the Blade templating system actually explained?

Or is it so new, or so "intuitive", that it needs no explanation? Or I could use another templating system that is better documented?

Answer (score 4):

I would say Blade is so easy that it doesn’t need documentation.

Follow this link great tutorial by Jeffrey Way which will take you through everything you need to know.

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/templating-changes/

Comment: Hi @GreGreg!

At time-lapse 4:35, in the video you referred, the narrator begins to speak about declaring layouts in views as suppose to in the controllers. Can you explain the purpose of having both features? Please provide an example if possible.

Comment: Everything needs documentation. Perhaps documentation needs documentation  about where to look for that documentation :-) .. The fact that so many people are looking for blade documentation .. says something about it.

Comment: @section('sarcasm')I would say Blade is so easy that it doesn’t need documentation.@stop

Comment: Easy or not, it still needs documentation. I did find a few examples on how to **get started**, but what when you want more? Saying that 'it's easy and it doesn't need documentation' will only made people angry. I'm also considering of using Smarty, since it has proper documentation and I found out on how to integrate it.

Comment: When it's your own code - it's 'self-documented'. When it's someone else's code - it's 'poorly documented'

Answer (score 2):

I am totally convinced that the original documentation about has many areas of opportunity. Anyway, Dayle Rees has done an excellent job through the pages of **Code Bright**. [The Blade section of the book](http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade) has some great examples that perfectly complement the original documentation. I find it strange that wasn't previously mentioned. You should [give it a look](http://daylerees.com/codebright).

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Blade isn't in the laravel.com docs. No, they tucked it away in their readthedocs.io account:

https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blade/